# Show popin if session is inactive

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my webappalication, i would show a popin if the session was inactive during 30 minutes.
Have you any idea about how to do that with SpringMVC?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

- Configure your container to expire sessions after 30mins
- When a user makes an initial request and a new session is created store a cookie which contains the session id.
- On subsequent requests check the session id on the request against the session id stored in the cookie, if they're different the user's previous session has expired and you should show a pop-up.

One more thing to note, ensure that you set the max age of the cookie to be negative. This ensures that the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed. If you don't do this, the next time the user opens their browser and goes to your site they will see the pop-up.